# selenium webdriver, select from datepicker

Tags: ruby, selenium-webdriver

I would like to know that is the corresponding code of this line in java for ruby :

```
driver.findElements(By.cssSelector
    ("button[data-pika-year='2017'][data-pika-month='11'][data-pika-day='22']")).get(0).click();
```

in java the above line was from this java code :

```
public void FlyDubaiDatePickerTest () throws InterruptedException {
//Go to website
driver.get("https://www.flydubai.com/en/");

//*****Departure day selection started.
//Click Departure Date
driver.findElement(By.id("departureDate")).click();

//Wait until departure table visible
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf(driver.findElements(By.cssSelector(".pika-table")).get(0)));

//Click departure day
driver.findElements(By.cssSelector
        ("button[data-pika-year='2017'][data-pika-month='11'][data-pika-day='22']")).get(0).click();
//*****Departure day selection finished.

//*****Return day selection started
//Click Return Date
driver.findElement(By.id("return-date")).click();

//Wait until departure table visible
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf(driver.findElements(By.cssSelector(".pika-table")).get(1)));

//Click return day
driver.findElements(By.cssSelector
        ("button[data-pika-year='2017'][data-pika-month='11'][data-pika-day='29']")).get(1).click();
//*****Return day selection finished.

//Check the operation in 5 seconds
Thread.sleep(5000);
}
```

Here is what I did :

```
driver.find_element(:css,"button[data-pika-year='2017'][data-pika-month='11'][data-pika-day='22']").click
```

Answer (score 0):

```
driver.find_elements(css: "button[data-pika-year='2017'][data-pika-month='11'][data-pika-day='22']")[0].click
```

Would be the same code. Are you getting a specific error you could share?